# Склонение мужского имени Валерий

Tags: орфография, склонение, ономастика, окончания

*На Валери**и** теплое пальто из шерсти.*
Или **-е**? Почему именно такое окончание?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Валерий

Answer (score 4):

Правила таковы (ПАС под ред. В. В. Лопатина):

> **1.** Существительные с неодносложной основой муж. и сред, рода на ***-ий*** и *-ие* в предл. п. и жен. рода на *-ия* в дат. и предл. п. ед. ч. имеют в безударном положении, в отступление от общего правила, окончание ***-и***, а не *-е*, напр.: ***гений – о гении, натрий – о натрии, радий – о радии, Василий – о Василии, Юрий – о Юрии**, отделение – в отделении, возвращение – по возвращении, содействие – при содействии; армия – к армии, об армии; линия – по линии, на линии; станция – к станции, на станции; Болгария – по Болгарии, в Болгарии; Мария – к Марии, о Марии.* <...>
> **2.** Немногочисленные существительные на ***-ий**, -ия* с односложной основой имеют в указанных падежах в безударном положении по общему правилу окончание *-е*. Перечень таких слов: *змий – о зми́е, кий – о ки́е* (вариант: *о кие́*), *Кий* (легендарный основатель Киева) – *о Кие, чий* (растение) *– о чие, «Вий» – в «Bue», Пий – о Пие, при папе Пие; хрия* (термин риторики) – *по хрие, о хрие; Бия* (река) *– по Бие, на Бие; Ия, Лия, Вия* (женские имена) *– к Ие, о Лие, о Bue; Гия* (мужское имя) *– к Гие, о Гие.*

Таких слов предостаточно: барий, калий, полоний, кремний (названия элементов); планетарий, гербарий, пролетарий, солярий, дельфинарий, жребий, аграрий, глоссарий, перигелий; Валерий, Геннадий, Евгений, Лаврентий, Афанасий, Дмитрий (имена).

*Однако Вера, оставшись без мужа, может повиснуть **на Валерии** Васильевиче, вцепившись в него мертвой хваткой* (А. Маринина. Иллюзия греха).

[Падежные формы существительных на -ий, -ие, -ия](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0_-%D0%B8%D0%B9,_-%D0%B8%D0%B5,_-%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

**Дополнение** (09.11.22)

Удаленный вопрос участника *Maksim Pushkin*:
*Верно ли я понимаю, что в примере "На Валерии теплое пальто из шерсти" невозможно без дополнительного контекста понять род объекта? Валерия это или Валерий?*

Верно понимаете. Кроме имени Валерий, имеются и другие "парные" имена, иногда нуждающиеся в контексте, например:
Клавдий, Евгений (*на Евгении Онегине* и *на Евгении Онегиной*), Анатолий, Аркадий, Аполлинарий, Леонтий, Юлий.

*Но и **в Клавдии** было некое чувство превосходства над Аллой Сергеевной* (В. Гроссман).
*При этом **в Леонтии** не было и тени лицемерия, двуличия, коварства* (А. Н. Бенуа).

Answer (score 1):

Обычно написание того или иного окончания существительного, коим является слово "Валерий", определяется по проверочному слову конкретного склонения (1,2 или 3). Однако существует ряд слов, окончание которых не проверяется данным способом. Для таких слов язык придумал свои правила.

---

Прежде всего это касается слов, которые оканчиваются в именительном падеже на:

- А)ИЯ (армИЯ, хотя окончание "я")
- Б)ИЕ (бденИЕ, хотя окончание "е")
- В)ИЙ (генИЙ, хотя окончание нулевое)

---

Все эти слова, а также подобные им, имеют в предложном падеже окончание "и". На ком/чём - на ВалерИИ. Слово Валерий в им. падеже оканчивается на "ий", поэтому окончание предложного падежа просто запоминаем.